# Multiple tags cdk bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cli

According to [this github-repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/design/cdk-bootstrap.md), it's possible to add multiple `--tags` when bootstrapping an AWS environment by running `cdk bootstrap`. I have tried finding answers online and have tried to solve it in multiple ways, but none has worked so far. This is the relevant part of my bootstrapping bash-script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

cdk bootstrap --profile $AWS_PROFILE aws://XXXXXXXXXX/eu-west-1 \
            --toolkit-stack-name some-toolkit-name \
            --bootstrap-bucket-name some-s3-bucket-name \
            --tags key1=value1,key2=value2
```

For example the result from the above, is 1 tag `key1=value1,key2`, not sure what happened with `value2` here. Below I outline other ways I have tried without success:

```
--tags (key1=value1, key2=value2) 
--tags {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"} 
--tags {"key1"="value1","key2"="value2"} 
--tags key1=value1 key2=value2
--tags key1=value1 --tags key2=value2
'--tags key1=value1,key2=value2'
--tags 'key1=value1,key2=value2'
--tags 'key1=value1 key2=value2'
--tags "key1=value1 key2=value2"
--tags "key1=value1,key2=value2"
--tags [key1=value1,key2=value2]
--tags "Key=key1,Value=value1 Key=key2,Value=value2"
--tags "Key"="key1","Value"="value1" "Key"="key2","Value"="value2"
--tags Key=key1,Value=value1 Key=key2,Value=value2
```

My `aws --version` is `aws-cli/2.0.59`, and my `cdk --version` is `1.115.0`.

Answer (score 6):

It got solved by writing `--tags` twice on two separate lines, like such

```
--tags key1=value1 \
--tags key2=value2
```